# How to find nodes with an object that contains a string value

Tags: mongodb

I'm struggling to create a find query that finds nodes that contain "Item1".

```json
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("589274f49bd4d562f0a15e07"),
  "Value" : [["Item1", {
        "Name" : "John",
        "Age" : 45
      }], ["Item2", {
        "Address" : "123 Main St.",
        "City" : "Hometown",
        "State" : "ZZ"
      }]]
}
```

In this example, "Item1" is not a key/value pair, but rather just a string that is part of an array that is part of a larger array. This is a legacy format so I can't adjust it unfortunately.

I've tried something like: `{ Value: {$elmemmatch:{$elemmatch:{"Item1"}}}`, but that is not returning any matches. Similarly, `$regex` is not working since it only seems to match on string objects (and the overall object is not a string, but a string in an array in an array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you should use the [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#use-the-in-operator-to-match-values-in-an-array) or [$eq](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/#equals-an-array-value) operator to match value.

So try this:

```
db.collection.find({'Value':{$elemMatch:{$elemMatch:{$in:['Item1']}}}})
```

Or run this to get the specific `Item`

```
db.collection.find({},{'Value':{$elemMatch:{$elemMatch:{$in:['Item1']}}}})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked. If possible, could you explain why? Why would `$in:['Item1']` match but not `$eq:"Item1"`?

Comment: @SimonGillbee Actually,you can use `eq`,too,it works well,you can check out the document from the link.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {  
"_id":"ObjectId('589274f49bd4d562f0a15e07')",
"Value":[  
  [  
     "Item1",
     {  
        "Name":"John",
        "Age":45
     }
  ],
  [  
     "Item2",
     {  
        "Address":"123 Main St.",
        "City":"Hometown",
        "State":"ZZ"
     }
   ]
 ]
}

data.Value[0][0] // 'Item1'
```

Copy and paste on repl it works.
There was an error on structure ofr your data

Comment: Oh sorry, It's not what you wanted (((